# changing checkbox style on uncheck - IE issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes in a page with all the boxes are checked by default. When user clicks on any particular checkbox to uncheck it, the background color of the checkbox should be changed or the boxes should be checked with cross mark in a red color.

Also, I would like to do this on some occasion not all the time. So, when the parent checkbox is checked and the child is unchecked, the style of the unchecked checkebox should be different. Whereas, if the parent is also not checked, then the child and the parent should be in normal style.

I tried the below solution.

CSS for red-x style:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: relative;
}
input[type=checkbox].awesome::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #808080 #808080;
    background-position: 0 -17px; 
    background-image: url(images/checkbox-x-red.png);
}
```

It is working fine in chrome. "Chrome : red-x css is applied"

It is not working in IE. "Internet  Explorer 11: red-x css ignored".

I tried

```
background-image:url(images/checkbox-x-red.png) !important;
```

also. Still it is not working.

Comment: plz provide ur html alsoo

Comment: Its a very big HTML. May I know what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: just want to know where you are using this `css` in `html `markup .. around that do u have any `div's`

Comment: can you please add HTML code